# Mount Google Drive on Linux

Tags: linux, google-drive

I see [Google Colab can mount Google Drive File Stream on Linux](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA).  How can I do the same on my local linux host?  Is there an official client?

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

```
Go to this URL in a browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=947318989803-6bn6qk8qdgf4n4g3pfee6491hc0brc4i.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdocs.test%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.photos.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fpeopleapi.readonly&response_type=code
Enter your authorization code:
··········
Mounted at /content/gdrive
```